# using Java stream if a string is found then add to a list and also add an extra element

Tags: java, lambda, stream

using streams i want to populate a string array if a match is found with the matching strings and then add a new string to the array.

example this code will return a list:

```
  List<String> source = Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three");
    String s ="Two-three-six-seven";

    List<String> target = source.stream()
            .filter(s.toLowerCase()::contains)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

}
```

creates a list (target) with "two" and "three" in it.

how can i now check that if the target list has a value then i add another value e.g. "numbers"
ending up with a list that has "two" "three" and "numbers"

I know this is possible by adding more code outside of the stream but I am trying to do all inside the stream

Comment: What is the expected result ?

Comment: `if (target.contains("two")) target.add("numbers");`

Comment: target array is "two" "three" and "numbers".
"numbers" is the new element added if the target array is not empty

Comment: I think you've missed the point of a stream.  Streams are for taking a taking a set of data, manipulating it, and outputting a modified set of data.  I won't say you can't add in data using a stream, somebody will probably bring up some hacky mapping method to do just that, but that just isn't what streams are meant for.  The cleanest solution would be to keep the code you have, and then add the extra element after the fact.

Comment: I would use a `Set` over a `List`, additionally

Answer (score 1):

As @Charlie Armstrong commented above, thats not a good use of a `Stream`.
However, if you still have to use a `Stream` for any reason, you can use `Collectors.collectingAndThen()`:

```
List<String> target = source.stream()
        .filter(s.toLowerCase()::contains)
        .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(),
                list -> list.isEmpty() ? list : 
                        Stream.concat(list.stream(), Stream.of("number"))
                                .collect(Collectors.toList())));

System.out.println(target);
```

**Output**

```
[two, three, number]
```